# How do i pass info from loginViewFetchedUserInfo: to multiple views at once

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication

Hi i am trying to pass the user.id and user.name from loginViewFetchedUserInfo: to my menuViewController, profileViewController and settingViewController so far i have sent the info to profileViewController with:

```
// this method will be called when the user information has been fetched
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{
//    self.profilePictureView.profileID = user.id;
//self.FBProfilePicture.profileID = user.id;

_profilePicture = user;
_FBNameString = user.name;

NSLog(@"%@, name from Login", _FBNameString);


[self pushViewController:user.name andProfilePicture:_profilePicture];
}


- (void)pushViewController:(NSString *)userName andProfilePicture:(id<FBGraphUser>)profilePicture
{

//    MenuViewController *menu = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuViewController"];
//    [menu setFBName:userName];
//    [menu setFBProfilePic:profilePicture];
//
//    SettingViewController *setting = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SettingViewController"];
//    [setting setFBName:userName];
//    [setting setFBProfilePic:profilePicture];

//    NSLog(@"%@",profilePicture);


//    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];



}
```

and i can only receive the info in the profileViewController and not the other i have put setters and getters i'm using protocols but i'm not able to get it to another viewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you method should be like this.(you may need to tweak as per requirement)

```
// this method will be called when the user information has been fetched
-(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user{

//    self.profilePictureView.profileID = user.id;
//self.FBProfilePicture.profileID = user.id;

_profilePicture = user.picture;//assuming you may be having picture property for object user
_FBNameString = user.name;

NSLog(@"%@, name from Login", _FBNameString);

//POST NOTIFICATION with desire object here its "user"
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"POSTLOGININFO" object:user];

//uncomment if you want this, ...depends on you 
//[self pushViewController:user.name andProfilePicture:_profilePicture];

}
```

Now update init method of your menuViewController.m, profileViewController.m and settingViewController.m class like below

```
-(id) init
{
  self = [super init];
  if (!self) 
   return nil;

  //Your custom code 

 //get registered for POSTLOGININFO notification so that selector method get called when you post notification with name POSTLOGININFO
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
      selector:@selector(gotLoginInfo:) 
          name:@"POSTLOGININFO"
              object:nil];
   return self;
}
```

Add new method gotLoginInfo: to each of your menuViewController.m, profileViewController.m and settingViewController.m

```
-(void)gotLoginInfo:(NSNotification *)notification{

    //Assuming FBGraphUser class have all required properties
    FBGraphUser *user = (FBGraphUser *)[notification object];

   // save user.id and user.name to your class local variable
    NSLog(@"UserID::%@ and username::%@",user.id,user.name);

}

 -(void)dealloc{

      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"POSTLOGININFO" object:nil];


 }
```

remove notification observer once you are done by using
"[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"POSTLOGININFO" object:nil];". Also be sure to have valid objects of your class menuViewController, profileViewController and settingViewController before loginViewFetchedUserInfo: get called

Comment: Are you able to show an example of the User Class that would be implemented with this so i can do it, also i have called the loginViewFetchUserInfo from my LoginViewController once the user has logged in so how would i pass that info and i was thinking would it be normal to have a Facebook class to use and pass the info from

Comment: Sorry that User Class is typo, i had corrected that,secondly you can pass any object through notification decision is yours.

Comment: you say to remove the NSNotificationCenter but in what method to i do that in the init method or..

Comment: it continues to say FBGraphUser undeclared class but i have imported the FB SDK

Comment: As we are adding notification in init we need to remove notification within dealloc method

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSNotification.
Example
There is a method named myTestNotificationReceived which is implemented in myClassA. Now I want to call this method from another class myClassB. Below is the code how I can do this using NSNotificationCenter.

```
    @implementation myClassA
- (void) dealloc{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
[super dealloc];
}
- (id) init
{
self = [super init];
if (!self) return nil;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(myTestNotificationReceived:) 
    name:@"myTestNotification"
    object:nil];
return self;
}
- (void) myTestNotificationReceived:(NSNotification *) notification
{
if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"myTestNotification"])
    NSLog (@"Notification is successfully received!");
}
@end
```

Now I want to call the method myTestNotification from myClassB.

```
@implementation myClassB
- (void) dealloc{
[super dealloc];
}
- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;
    return self;
}
- (void) myMethod
{
// All instances of myClassA will be notified
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    postNotificationName:@"myTestNotification" 
    object:self];
}
@end
```

Now you can add as many observer in your different classes.

Comment: i just tried your example here just to see and nothing happens is there a better and more in depth example or tutorial you could show me on how to pass facebook info to mutliple views at once